# How to plot a backward bifurcation diagram?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Bifurcation Diagram: I want to know how to plot the bifurcation diagram below using Mathematica, I modify a code seen here on the platform but still no get the actual diagram
here is my code:

```
Clear[c]
ClearAll[f]
f[c_, x_] := m + Subscript[b, 0]*x  +  Subscript[a, 0]*x^2 ;

Subscript[a, 0] = v β μ ω;
Subscript[b, 0] = β (μ ω - ϵ v A (μ + δ));

m = μ (μ + δ) (μ + γ) (μ + ϵ) (1 - c);

ω = γ (μ + ϵ + δ) + (μ + γ) (μ + ϵ);
v = 0.000056;
A = 10;
μ = 0.000365;
β = 0.000001473197393;
ϵ = 0.3;
γ = 0.04;
δ = 0.2;
ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[
    f[c, x], (D[f[c, t], t] /. t -> x) <= 0] == 0, 
  ConditionalExpression[f[c, x], (D[f[c, t], t] /. t -> x) > 0] == 
   0}, {c, 0, 1.5
  }, {x, 0, 50000}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[("D[f[c, x], x] ≤ 0"), 18, "Panel"],
    Style[("D[f[c, x], x] > 0"), 18, "Panel"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Running your code, I get a diagram that looks similar to Fig. 1.  What do you get?

Comment: @ChrisK, there is a slight different between my diagram and the one presented. in my diagram the value of Rc is 0.6884 compared to 0.995 on the presented diagram. also at the origin there is blue line that indicate stable DFE on the graph presented.

Comment: I see, it's more a quantitative disagreement rather than not getting any output.  Could you provide more background info?  What is the reference?

Comment: Its a compartmental model to study the spread of a disease. the model is solve in term of the infective compartment denoted with  "I" written in term of the basic reproduction number Ro, which is a threshold to determine if the disease will persist or die out. so the objective is to varry R0 to study the dynamics of the system.  see https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5df7/a22a3faf7d7dc0d3f2281061455bf15aa99d.pdf

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) The bifurcation code you use is appropriate for a one-dimensional system, but this is a four-dimensional system. The ${a_0 I^*}^2+b_0 I^*+c_0$ equation is not $dI/dt$ so the stability analysis is off and the trivial $I=0$ solution does not appear.  2) $R_0$ is not an independent, free parameter, but is a combination of other model parameters (eqn. 6 in the paper).  It's not clear to me what actual parameter they varied to generate figure 1.

Comment: @ChrisK from (eqn 9 in the paper) the constant term C0 is expressed in term of R0 so that it can be varied in e a0I∗2+b0I∗+c0, all parameter are supplied except the valued for calculated R0=0.997

Comment: I don't have time to study this paper closely, but it seems that there's something weird in this figure - $R_0$ is on the x-axis, but the legend also says "With this set of parameters, ... $R_0=0.9987000002$".  So, is $R_0$ an independent variable or is it a constant?

Comment: Can someone please help me out. I need help on this